# Adding and using new database models with NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/) to create a web service and connected it to a MongoDB database. I'm now able to log in with Google Auth and the records are saving correctly to my database. I now need to add new models to my database and add to them via API routes.

I followed [these instructions](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/typeorm-custom-models) to add a custom model `Test`.

**Test.js**

```js
export default class Test {
  constructor(name) {
    if (name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
}

export const TestSchema = {
  name: 'Test',
  target: Test,
  columns: {
    id: {
      // This property has `objectId: true` instead of `type: int` in MongoDB
      primary: true,
      type: 'int',
      generated: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: 'varchar',
      nullable: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'timestamp',
      createDate: true,
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'timestamp',
      updateDate: true,
    },
  },
};
```

**index.js**

```js
import Test, { TestSchema } from './Test';

export default {
  Test: {
    model: Test,
    schema: TestSchema,
  },
};
```

The I updated **[...nextauth.js]** to add `Test` to my adapter

```js
adapter: Adapters.TypeORM.Adapter(
  process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  {
    models: {
      Test: Models.Test,
    },
  }
)
```

At this point I'm not seeing any errors but I'm not sure it's added correctly. So I want to try to create a test `Test` document. However, I can't find any documentation on *how* to do this. I need to have access to the database connection but I've tried logging everything imported from  'next-auth/adapters', 'next-auth/client', 'next-auth', req, etc. and can't find anywhere that this connection is stored. I'd think I need to call the `getAdapter()` function stored in the TypeORM Adapter class but I can't seem to access it. I also tried accessing any of the built in methods like `setUser` and can't get those either. So I can't find any way to manually modify database records.

Comment: I'm also learning these set up steps too, but the docs available aren't helping much... Anyway, I've came across a GitHub project example which uses the NextAuth Type.ORM Adapter and it looks like the user properties should be assigned properly like on Line#6 https://github.com/shanoysinc/fitur/blob/main/server/model/User.ts#L6

Comment: If you find a solution, please leave us an insight here or a link to your repo! Thanks!